# Android make mp4 video file smaller

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

Is there a way to quickly implement a size reduction of an mp4 video file? Say, I have a full-HD video recorded on the device camera and I need to transfer it over the network so I need to make the video size smaller.

I have read a bunch of docs about `MediaCodec`, `MediaExtractor`, `MediaMuxer`, etc, however all the examples were like several hundred lines of code! I can't believe there is no high level APIs to do this.

Here is an example how it is done in iOS:

```
    let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
    exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously { // DONE! }
```

**That's it, 6 lines of code!** Is there something similar to this in Android?

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no higher abstraction level for what you want to achieve in the AOSP.
If you don't want to experiment with `MediaCodec` etc. there are libraries you can use.

[Transcoder](https://github.com/natario1/Transcoder) for example looks like a promising project. It uses strategies i have used myself. Like letting the codec fail instead of assuming what will happen beforehand. It also offers a lot of non standard operations.

*I'm not affiliated with the project nor have i used it myself*

Comment: if it is something u want to do offline, please use handbrake, afaik there is no direct way other than using FFmpeg which will consume significant battery.